# Merge 2 LAN Connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, lan

I have an internet connection on the ground foor. I'm receiving it on computer X (using long range WiFi receiver) on my 4th Floor. Now I'm using ICS to share Internet to my new router (on the 4th floor as well). I am using this new router because my other computers on the 4th floor cannot catch WiFi from the ground floor.

Now, I want to share files on X, using localhost (by Apache Tomcat server). But X is part of ground floor LAN and so its localhost cannot be viewed on the 4th floor LAN.

How I can enable localhost of X on my 4th floor?

Limitations:

1. X has only one ethernet port i.e. used in ICS. If it had another ethernet port I would have used it to connect to my 4th floor router, but that's not possible.
2. I cannot setup X as a proxy server. Because cell phones on the 4th Floor won't work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already set up ICS on the X computer, all you have to do is to turn off DHCP on the 4th-floor router. This way all requests of IP addresses will go to the first floor router, which will distribute them also to the fourth floor pcs, among which there is yours. At this point, all machines, on the first floor and on the fourth floor, belong to the same subnet, and your shared folder becomes visible to all pcs, on the first and on the fourth floor.